# Issue printing out objects from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

First i have a class called card with this code

```
public class Card
{
private int value;
private String suit;
// private int value;
//private String rank;
public Card (int v, String s)
{
    value=v;
suit=s;
}

public int random()
{
    int randomNum = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % 13 +1);
    return randomNum;
}

public void displayCard()
{
    System.out.println(value + " of " + suit);
}

}
```

then i have a class called deck with this code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deck 
{
public ArrayList<Card> card;
private ArrayList<String> suits;
private ArrayList<Card> hand;


public Deck()// time to build a deck
{

    card=new ArrayList<>();
    suits=new ArrayList<>();

    suits.add("Hearts");
    suits.add("Spades");
    suits.add("Clubs");
    suits.add("Diamonds");

    for (int y=2; y<15; y++)
        {
            card.add(new Card(y,suits.get(0)));
        }

    for (int y=2; y<15; y++)
        {
            card.add(new Card((y),suits.get(1)));
        }

    for (int y=2; y<15; y++)
        {
            card.add(new Card((y),suits.get(2)));
        }

    for (int y=2; y<15; y++)
        {
            card.add(new Card((y),suits.get(3)));
        }



}//end of public deck


public ArrayList deal()// deal method
{
    hand=new ArrayList<>();


    for(int x = 0; x < 5; ++x)//build 5 card hand
        {
        hand.add(card.get(x));

        System.out.println(card.get(x));

         }

    return hand;

}//end of public void deal

}// end of public class deck
```

then i have the main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.*;

public class gamePlay 
    {
        private static gamePlay player1;
        public Deck fullDeck;
        private ArrayList<Card> yourHand;


    public gamePlay()
    {
        fullDeck=new Deck();
        System.out.println("Your poker hand is a");
        yourHand = fullDeck.deal();

        //System.out.println(yourHand);

    }
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
player1 = new gamePlay();        
}
}
```

It is printing out some crazy stuff for the value and suit of the cards in the hand 
i think they are either memory locations from the arraylist or hexidecimal values i am not sure need it to print suit and rank any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

If your classes implement a proper `toString` method, it will show up perfectly.

You can easily change your existing method `displayCard` in the `Card` class to a `toString` method. This leads to more flexibility than to let the `Card` print out itself by calling `System.out.println` in the card's method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return value + " of " + suit;
}
```

If you want the card to print to System.out you just do `System.out.println(card);`

Normal arrays can also be converted to String, using `Arrays.toString(array)` (if you would have a `Card[]` variable for example). Most implementations of `List`s already implement a proper `toString` method so it will show you a comma-separated list of the entries.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a `toString()` method in your `Card` class.

For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Card [value=%s, suit=%s]", value, suit);
}
```

If you don't provide that method, the default depends on the JDK implementation. Usually, it is the name of the class followed by a `@` and the object hash code.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you have to iterate through the array and print each item individually. One cannot print the entire content of an array by toString() the array itself.

Comment: There is `Arrays.toString(array)` that can be used. And this question is about `List`s rather than arrays.

Comment: `Arrays.toString(array)` is for arrays. Here we have an `ArrayList`, no?

Comment: yeah i have to iterate through it to print each card.